# Chicken & Egg: How to keep PHP out of public_html if .htaccess needs to link to it?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to build good security habits, so I'd like to move my sensitive PHP files outside the public_html directory. My setup is LAMP (Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5) with the following directory structure:

- /home/username/public_html
- /home/username/src

The sensitive files are in `/src`.  My previous setup had that folder at `/home/username/public_html/src` and I had some .htaccess rules directing users there, such as

> `RewriteRule ^myaccount$   src/account.php`

Now that the script is out of public_html, I'm not sure how to redirect it from htaccess (all paths in htaccess are relative to `/home/username/public_html`)

I read about the `Alias` directive from [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html) which would allow me to set a directive such as `Alias /src /home/username/src` but that doesn't work in `.htaccess` and I would rather not change the `httpd[-vhosts].conf` unless that's the best way to solve my problem.

**SOLUTION**
credit: @Idealcastle (below) inspired a solution which allows me to keep my sensitive files out of `public_html` while still allowing htaccess to link to them.

I changed .htaccess directive from `^myaccount$ /src/account.php` to `^myaccount$ redirect.php?file=account.php`.  I then created a gateway script which includes the script file I am trying to protect. `redirect.php` is in the public_html folder and has the contents below:

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['file'])):
    //the file argument is missing
    http_response_code(400); //bad request
    exit;
else:        
    $file = rawurlencode($_GET['file']);
    $path = "/home/username/src/$file";
    //Check the file against a whitelist of approved files. if it's not
    //on the list, exit with http_response_code(403): Access Forbidden

    //seek the file from its private location
    require $path;
endif;
```

This code will insert the right file based on the value of the `file` argument set in `.htaccess`

Comment: I'd really like to know the "chicken & egg" analogy?

Comment: I wanted my PHP files out of `public_html`, but to I needed .htaccess to refer to them and .htaccess can't point to files outside `public_html`, so I needed PHP files within `public_html`, but I wanted my PHP files out of `public_html`...  Maybe a race condition analogy would have been more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want to redirect or make public access the `/src` directory as it defeats the purpose of what you are doing.

If I understand you correctly, how about linking specific files in `/public_html` to the ones in `/src` for script execution.

Such as `/home/username/public_html/account.php`

inside this file you would have

`<?php include('/home/username/src/account.php'); ?>`

Now the public can access files you allow it to. and the `/src` is protected from direct script execution.

And then for your htaccess, do the same thing,

`RewriteRule ^myaccount$   /home/username/public_html/account.php`

but instead make it go to the public html.

Comment: Yep. Keeping your scripts (and **especially** configuration files) outside of the web root, except for your designated entry points (e.g. `index.php`, `app.php`) is the best practice here.

Comment: I tried to implement what you guys suggested. Please take a look at my edited OP and let me know if you see any glaring flaws